# JPanel on free space after tabs

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I want to add a `JPanel` after the last tab in a `JTabbedPane`

I have this:
[image: Tengo esto-I have This]

And I want something like this:
[image: Quiero Esto-I want this]

The most important part is that the layout of the `JPanel` after tabs can vary and needs to be resized when main `JFrame` is resized.

I tried with `OverlayLayout`, `JLayeredPane` and with Glass Panel but without luck.

Comment: You'd have to get into the look and feel delegate for the `JTabbedPane` I think to determine how it lays out it's tabs...

Comment: Right now, I'm making a new Tab that the component of Tab title is a `JPanel` with all what I need(buttons, textbox, label, etc) but I need to make the last tab title full width.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried with OverlayLayout,

Here is an example that works with OverlayLayout that works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class TabbedPaneWithComponent
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(panel) );

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("1", new JTextField("one"));
        tabbedPane.add("2", new JTextField("two"));
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check Me");
        checkBox.setOpaque( false );
        checkBox.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        checkBox.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        panel.add( checkBox );
        panel.add(tabbedPane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane With Component");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Of course it only works it there is space available to display the components.

The only proper solution is to create a custom tabbed pane UI that allows you to add a component to the right. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: plus one, with GBC is possible too, to create a floating aka toolbar (nicer by using JMenu instead of JPanel)

Comment: I tried this before, but with a `JPanel` instead of a `JCheckBox` does not work, al least for me. I made it with new tab with custom component on title, and some changes on CustomTabbedPaneUI. Now it's looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz8VTzJV6y1FY0otMGZXZzR0QUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @jotapdiez, `with a JPanel instead of a JCheckBox does not work` - it works, sort of, but you need to set the maximum size of the panel equal to the preferred size, otherwise the panel will paint over the tabbed pane. `I made it with new tab with custom component on title, and some changes on CustomTabbedPaneUI.` As I suggest that is a better approach. You should post your solution as an answer. It may benefit other users of the forum.